# JavaScript Class Methods Not Being Executed

Tags: javascript, class, methods

I have been having some trouble with making classes in JavaScript. I've looked at a lot of examples but can't seem to make them something I understand. The `alerts()` never occur below.

```
function Player(){

    function run(){

        alert('run');
        self.update();
        self.draw();

    }

    function draw(){
        alert('draw');
    }

    function update(){
        alert('update');
    }

}

var player1 = new Player();
player1.run();
```

Comment: Inspect your JavaScript error console, it's telling you exactly what is wrong.

Comment: constructor, not class

Comment: I am not getting errors in the console. Would I have to change settings through the server service hosting the site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the functions using self.name = function(){}

```
function Player(){
    var self = this;
    self.run = function(){

        alert('run');
        self.update();
        self.draw();

    }

    self.draw = function(){
        alert('draw');
    }

    self.update = function(){
        alert('update');
    }

}

var player1 = new Player();
player1.run();
```

Comment: I never knew I had to declare `self` as `this`, I've never had to do that before. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: No problem!
It is handy to store the original value for `this` in a variable so the inner functions can reference it.  Those inner functions get their own `this`, so `this.update();` would not work if it was inside of the run function.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax is a little off..

```
function Player(){

    this.run = function(){

        alert('run');
        self.update();
        self.draw();

    }

    ....
}
```

do them all like that..

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this leveraging one of the following patterns...

```
function Player() {
    this.run = function() {
        /*...*/
    }
}
```

or

```
function Player() {
    function run() {
        /*...*/
    }

    return {
        run: run
    }
}
```

or

```
function Player() {
}

Player.prototype.run = function() {
    /*...*/
};
```

For a deeper read on these patterns, check out this nice writeup: [3 ways to define a JavaScript class](http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/)

Answer (score 0):

As other answers have pointed out, the inner functions have not been exposed as part of the actual class (i.e. they are not *public* methods).

Define the public methods of your class as follows:

```
function Player(){

    //PUBLIC!
    this.run = function(){
        //...
    }

    //NOT PUBLIC
    function update(){
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it looks like you're doing game development, you're going to want to adopt some more javascript-centric OOP paradigms.  If you're making a class, define the instance methods on the prototype, not the function itself.

Why? Because when you're performance tweaking your game, every ms or bit of memory counts (unless you're making a tic-tac-toe game or something trivial).  But it's a good habit.

```
function Player(){}

Player.prototype.run = function(){ ... }
Player.prototype.draw = function(){ ... }
Player.prototype.update = function(){ ... }

var player1 = new Player();
player1.run();
```